# regedit - import *.reg

Tags: shell, batch-file, regedit

It has two types of records (64 and 32 bit) and realize the import with this command:

```
regedit /s "TEST(64bits).reg"
```

In this way it works perfectly.
Does anyone know how to import the registry with different names?

```
regedit /s "*(64bits).reg"
```

I will always have brackets to architetura OS,

would like to import as their suffix, someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Regedit needs an actual non-wildcard file

Instead use a loop a loop to resolve the filename, then call regedit

```
FOR %%F in ("*(64bits).reg") DO regedit /s "%%F"
```

Note: use `%%F` in a batchfile or just `%F` if typing into the cmd window

Comment: You actually need to write `regedit /s "%%~F"` to not get double-double-quotes...